# Source build of Python interpreter fails when compiling with clang on Centos7

Tags: python

On Centos 7, with `clang 14.0.0`, I have attempted to build Python3.9.13 from source via:

```
Python-3.9.13 % ./configure --disable-ipv6 --with-address-sanitizer --with-undefined-behavior-sanitizer --with-pydebug --prefix=/foo/bar
```

The `configure` stage goes through without issue, but the build stage fails with:

```
./python -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars ;\
if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
    echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
    rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
    exit 1 ; \
fi
python: Objects/unicodeobject.c:5424: int _Py_EncodeUTF8Ex(const wchar_t *, char **, size_t *, const char **, int, _Py_error_handler): Assertion `ch <= 0x10ffff' failed.
/bin/sh: line 5: 179960 Aborted                 ./python -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

What can I do to fix this issue or workaround it?

First attempt at triage: I have discovered that without the `--with-address-sanitizer --with-undefined-behavior-sanitizer` flags, the build succeeds; however, I have no cause to source build the python interpreter unless I add these flags.

Second attempt: I have commented out the `assert` in `Objects/unicodeobject.c:5424`; then the build fails with:

```
Fatal Python error: init_interp_main: can't finish initializing sys
Python runtime state: core initialized
ValueError: character U+6f002f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

Third attempt: The second attempt indicated that it might be a locale problem. So I:

```
setenv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8
setenv LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
```

The build now *kinda* succeeds, but emits the following error message:

```
=================================================================
==204413==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 88 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x59e22e in malloc /temp/llvm-project-14.0.0.src/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69:3
    #1 0x60d31b in _PyMem_RawMalloc ~/Python-3.9.13/Objects/obmalloc.c:99:12
    #2 0x611c77 in _PyMem_DebugRawAlloc ~/Python-3.9.13/Objects/obmalloc.c:2145:24
```

However, the python interpreter is nonetheless created, so might as well try it:

```
Python-3.9.13 % ./python
Python 3.9.13 (main)
[Clang 14.0.0 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Objects/call.c:400:23: runtime error: applying zero offset to null pointer
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior Objects/call.c:400:23 in
```

Hmm.

Comment: The code which is triggering the UBsan error is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.13/Objects/call.c#L400 Appears that stack is NULL and nargs is 0. Reading the asserts, that appears to be intentionally allowed.